# Is calling a subroutine inside Parallel.For (and passing a variable ByRef to it) thread safe?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, parallel-processing, thread-safety, parallel.for

I call a subroutine MyPartsMatrix inside nested Parallel.For loops (vb.net).  MyPartsMatrix requires a variable called "unfilled" that is passed ByRef because this value is modified inside MyPartsMatrix subroutine.  I need to grab and store this value after the subroutine MyPartsMatrix executes.

The "unfilled" variable yields a different value when I run the parallel version of this code compared to a one that is non-parallel, using normal nested For...Next loops. I can't figure out why this is the case.

Is it thread safe to call another subroutine from inside the Parallel.For loop?

Is this variable "unfilled" thread safe?

```
    Dim ConcurrentListofResults As ConcurrentQueue(Of FindBestResults)
    ConcurrentListofResults = New ConcurrentQueue(Of FindBestResults)

    Dim x = 5, y = 5

    Parallel.For(0, x, Sub(oD)
                           Parallel.For(0, y, Sub(oT)

                                                  Dim unfilled As Integer = 0
                                                  MyPartsMatrix (oD, oT, unfilled)

                                                  'Create a FBS item to add to the concurrent list collection
                                                  Dim FBSResultsItem = New FindBestResults
                                                  FBSResultsItem.oD = oD
                                                  FBSResultsItem.oT = oT
                                                  FBSResultsItem.unfilled = unfilled

                                                  'Add this item to the Concurent collection
                                                  ConcurrentListofResults.Enqueue(FBSResultsItem)

                                              End Sub)
                       End Sub)
    'Get best result.
    Dim bestResult As FindBestResults
    For Each item As FindBestResults In ConcurrentListofResults
        If item.unfilled < bestResult.unfilled Then
            bestResult.oD = item.oD
            bestResult.oT = item.oT
            bestResult.unfilled = item.unfilled
        End If
    Next

    Public Sub MyPartsMatrix (ByVal oD As Integer, ByVal oT As Integer, ByRef unfilled As Integer)

      '....do stuff with the unfilled variable....
      'unfilled is a counter that is incremented while we run through the PartsMatrix
       unfilled = unfilled + 1  
    End Sub
```

If this is not thread safe, is there another way to write this so that the "unfilled" variable is thread safe or to make calling another subroutine thread safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the definition of `MakeSchedule` (which you've called `MyMakePartsMatrix` in another place) it's impossible to say whether it's thread safe.

To be threadsafe the sub needs to not modify anything other than unfilled. This will ensure that calling it multiple times with the same inputs will always yield the same outputs. I'd also recommend converting to a function as I find this much easier to understand whats happening.

On another note:

Your performance will be better if you don't nest parallel loops. You're currently waiting for your inner loop to finish before launching your second loop. If you're using larger x + y values then something similar to the code will work better.

```
    Dim scenarios = From x2 In Enumerable.Range(0, x)
        From y2 In Enumerable.Range(0, y)
        Select New With {x2, y2}

    Parallel.ForEach(scenarios, Sub(s)

                                End Sub)
```

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the discrepancies in my sample code. I didn't want to paste the entire thing in there so, I tried to simplify things for readability.   Unfilled variable is basically a counter that is incremented inside of the Subroutine MyPartsMatrix. You mentioned considering a function -- do you mean change MyPartsMatrix from a Sub to a function (returning unfilled) or should I change the lambda section from Sub to a Function?  Still new at the parallel.for concept so I'm actually not really sure what the difference between these two are.Thanks for the suggestion about not nesting the loops!

Comment: Also, the code creating the scenarios collection looks like a great idea! So this creates a collection of items that cover (0,0) to (x,y)?  If so, how do I access the x2 and y2 value inside the parallel.foreach statement.  Can I just use the variable x2 and y2 because the need to passed into the MyPartsMatrix subroutine.   Finally, is this using LINQ?

Comment: If you use a sub with one output parameter I generally change it to a function, just my personal preference, it doesn't really change how things work. Yes, this is linq. To access the variable inside the `ForEach` use `s.x2` and `s.y2`. In this example unfilled will always be 1 when it is returned so I suspect you're doing something more involved in there. Bear in mind though that if your sub modifies anything other than unfilled, oD or oT then it's probably not being threadsafe. If you post the actual code I can help you fix up the issue.